How can I code my HTML to call specific layout of keyboard?
I'm setting up a captive portal for our business Wi-Fi. I used the "number" input type in HTML for easier input, but the keyboard that appears has a Tab button (like image 2). While I've configured the JavaScript to handle the Tab button as Enter, I'd prefer for the button itself to visually display "Enter" or "Go" instead of "Tab" (like image 1).
Image 1
Image 2
<input type="number"
 maxlength="7"
 id="voucherCode"
 name="voucherCode"
 placeholder="VOUCHER CODE"
 inputmode="numeric"
 style="
   -webkit-appearance: textfield;
   -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
">


I tried to modify to use TEL as input but it shows letters

controlling the exact labels on virtual keyboard buttons (like changing "Tab" to "Enter" or "Go") is generally not possible due to browser and device limitations.

It's not possible in general , It's limitation issues
